# После обновления Angular Visual Studio 2017 перестал обновлять данные

Tags: angular2, visual-studio-2017

В общем, обновил Angular с 5 версии до 7.

Ранее, я нажимал F5 и я видел изменения которые я продел, а сейчас же я их не вижу, хотя в output Visual Studio ошибок нету...

В тоже время, когда я запускаю из консоли ng build, то все успешно билдится и студия берет последние изменения.

Как сделать, что бы по F5 студия все сама делала, как это было ранее.

в package.json прописано это:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
```

и я ничего не менял.

Comment: Помогло удаление папки dst в ClientApp [Сорс](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53694965/4244707)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгого поиска я нашел [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53694965/4244707) .

После того, как я удалил папку dst из ClientApp, студия начала нормально все собирать и детектить изменения.